# select count wise records till a limit

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a data table like below and I want to update column flag in that based on below mention condition.

```
declare @tbl table (id int identity  ,supergroup int ,subgroup int , flag char(1)  )
```

The objective is to fetch top 40 records in total based on supergroup and subgroup like 40/count(distinct subgroup ) where supergroup = @subgroup 
till 40 records.
suppose there are 3 supergroup and  if for supergroup 1000 there are 3 distinct subgroup then fetch 40/3 =13 records and for next supergroup 2000 there are again 3 distinct subgroup 
then fetch 13 records from that,  for next supergroup 3000 if there are again 3 subgroup then 40/3=13 logic will sum up only 39 so I need 14 from the last supergroup.

in any scenario, I need exact 40 records.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you can do:

```
select top (40) t.*
from @tbl t
order by row_number() over (partition by supergroup, subgroup order by newid());
```

This will do a round-robin selection from the supergroups and subgroups, returning one row from each before getting a second row from the same group.

EDIT:

If you need to do a round-robin of the supergroups first, then I think this will do that:

```
select top (40) t.*
from @tbl t
order by row_number() over (partition by supergroup order by subgroup, newid());
```

However, this is likely to get all the results from one `subgroup`.  Let's try again:

```
select top (40) t.*
from @tbl t
order by row_number() over (partition by supergroup order by newid()),
         row_number() over (partition by supergroup, subgroup order by newid());
```

Comment: @Gordon Linoff , query is giving 40 records but i need to include all supersectors data according to count of subsector to make it 40 and in exception if they cannot make 40 then any one should select more. 

Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @hieko . . . I think the revision does what you want:  sampling evenly from supergroups and then sampling evenly from subgroups.